# Enter line-breaks / carriage returns between the XAttributes in a XElement.ToString result

Tags: c#, .net, xelement

Is there no way to get line-breaks to appear between attributes in the XElement.ToString resultant xml string?

The following didn't work -- it kept the line-breaks, but put them below all the attributes, so there were just 4/5 empty lines:

```
new XElement("options", new XText("\r\n"),
    new XAttribute("updated", Updated.XmlTime()), new XText("\r\n"),
    new XAttribute("color", Color), new XText("\r\n"),
    new XAttribute("puppies", Puppies), new XText("\r\n"),
    new XAttribute("isTrue", IsTrue), new XText("\r\n"),
    new XAttribute("kitties", Kitties ?? "")),
```

Comment: Well yes, it would - text nodes are part of the *contents* of an element, which always come after the end of the start tag... (I don't know how or even *if* you can affect the formatting to that extent though.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using a `XmlWriter`. Try this:

```
public static string ToStringFormatted(this XElement xml)
{
  XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
  settings.Indent = true;
  settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(result, settings)) {
    xml.WriteTo(writer);
  }
  return result.ToString();
} // ToStringFormatted
```

then

```
var xml =new XElement("options",
    new XAttribute("updated", "U"),
    new XAttribute("color", "C"),
    new XAttribute("puppies", "P"),
    new XAttribute("isTrue", "I"),
    new XAttribute("kitties", "K")
 );
 Console.WriteLine(xml.ToStringFormatted());
```

produces this:

```
<options
  updated="U"
  color="C"
  puppies="P"
  isTrue="I"
  kitties="K" />
```

You can have different formatting using the various [`XmlWriterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx) properties.

Comment: If this is what he/she is in fact trying to do. edit those to be XAttributes

Comment: Awesome! Now I need to also mess around with XmlWriterSettings in thinking of a few other customizations in the serialization to a string that I've pondered on if they were possible before. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to put new lines inside XML object because there is no "text nodes" in XML DOM between attributes. All attributes for each node are in on big unordered* table and there is no "text-only" attributes.

Only text representation of XML can have such formatting of attributes. Note that all formatting between attributes will be lost on when such XML loaded in DOM/reader.

What you may be able to do is implement your own XmlWriter with formatting you want.

*) most XML DOM implementations keep order of attributes as in source or order they are added, but there is no requirement to do so.